# Load pandas dataframe into Spark cluster

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a postgres database and I want to run a query and load a table into spark dataframe. some columns of my database are array. For example:

```
=> select id, f_2 from raw limit 1;
```

will return

```
    id   |  f_2  
---------+-----------
 1       | {{140,130},{NULL,NULL},{NULL,NULL}}
```

what I want is accessing to `140` (first element of inner array) that is easy in postgres using this query:

```
=> select id, f_2[1][1] from raw limit 1;
        id   |  f_2  
    ---------+-----------
     1       | 140
```

but I want to load it into spark dataframe and here is my code to load data:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("""
select id as id,
f_2 as A
from raw
""")
```

and return this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o560.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

and then I tried this one:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("""
select id as id,
f_2[0] as A
from raw
""")
```

and got same error and then tried this one:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("""
select id as id,
f_2[0][0] as A
from raw
""")
```

and return this error:

```
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))

AnalysisException: u"Can't extract value from f_2#32685[0];"
```

Comment: Can you check your scala version ? Spark application version and spark cluster version ?

Comment: I'm using  Scala 2.11.8, and both Spark's application and cluster are 2.1.1 any code is running on Jupyter notebook under Python 2.